# Sumproduct to be evaluated in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formulas

I am new to Excel. I need to do evaluate Sum-product in VBA Excel.

Here's my worksheet:

[image]

- Cell D4 contains Particular Date (Highlighted Yellow)
- Cell D6 contains new entered Date (Highlighted Red)
- Column C contains Legend.(Highlighted Pink)
- Column J Contains Month. (Highlighted Green)
- Column K Contains Legend of the That Particular Transaction. (Highlighted Orange)
- Column I contains values to be summed (Highlighted Blue)
- Column D9 onwards will show the result of sum product (Highlighted Grey)

What I trying to do is that:

I would enter a date in Cell# D6 which will should sum Column I with the help of matching month of Column J with Cell D6 and if Matched then It will Match Legend of Column K with That of the Legend in Column C and if then matched again it will sum the Column I and Show it value in Column D9 onwards.

This is the formula i used and it worked without VBA.

```
SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($J$9:$J$12000)=MONTH($D$6))*($K$9:$K$12000=C10)*($I$9:$I$12000))
```

Purpose of Using VBA is to use While Loop. When I enter a date in D6 for a particular month then it should increment or decrement Month and add them till another specified date cell D4(Highlighted Yellow).

But when i use the said formula it returns #Value.

```
Sub Sub1()
Dim a, b, c As Integer
a = Sheet20.Cells(6, 4)
b = 4
c = 10
Do While a >= Cells(4, 4)
Sheet20.Cells(c, b).Value = Evaluate(" (SumProduct((Month(Sheet20.Range(J9:J12000)) = Month(Cells(6, 4))) * (Sheet20.Range(K9:K12000) = Cells(c, 3)) * (Sheet20.Range(I9:I12000)))")
 a = a - 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Is the above taking the range correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I have added a proper reference to the worksheet you are using. In VBA you need to first specify that "Sheet20" is a Worksheet.

Thus I replaced "Sheet20" with `Worksheets("Worksheet20")` thereby making it clear that it is part of the worksheets collection.

```
Sub Sub1()
Dim a, b, c As Integer
a = Worksheets("Sheet20").Cells(6, 4)
b = 4
c = 10
Do While a >= Cells(4, 4)
Worksheets("Sheet20").Cells(c, b).Value = Evaluate(" (SumProduct((Month(Sheet20.Range(J9:J12000)) = Month(Cells(6, 4))) * (Sheet20.Range(K9:K12000) = Cells(c, 3)) * (Sheet20.Range(I9:I12000)))")
 a = a - 1
Loop
End Sub
```